# ms sql - результирующий столбец в сложном запросе

Tags: sql-server, select

Есть запрос к MS SQL Standart

```
SELECT [ConceptionName],[mainRoleCode],[UserName], [UnitTabel] as staff, 
CAST([DateTime] AS date) AS date into #Test 
FROM[Authorization] WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '2019-01-21T00:00:00' AND '2019-01-24T00:00:00'  

SELECT[ConceptionName],[mainRoleCode],[UserName],sum(staff)[staff],[date] 
into #TestPivot 
FROM #Test group by [ConceptionName],[mainRoleCode],[UserName],[date] 
SELECT[date] into #TestPivotDate 
FROM #Test 
GROUP BY [date] 
DECLARE @Dates nvarchar(MAX); select @Dates = stuff((select ',' + '[' + left(convert(nvarchar,[date], 120), 10) + ']' 
FROM #TestPivotDate ORDER BY [date] FOR xml path('')),1,1,'') DECLARE @SqlCode nvarchar(MAX); 
SELECT @SqlCode = 'select [ConceptionName],[mainRoleCode],[UserName],' + @Dates + ' FROM #TestPivot pivot(sum([staff]) for [date] in (' + @Dates + ')) AS pvt ORDER BY [ConceptionName]' 
EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCode 
DROP TABLE #Test,#TestPivot,#TestPivotDate
```

Он выдает такую таблицу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добавить результирующий столбец выводящий итог прихода на работу за период. Как на примере :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
SELECT [ConceptionName],[mainRoleCode],[UserName], [UnitTabel] as staff, 
CAST([DateTime] AS date) AS date into #Test 
FROM[Authorization] WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '2019-01-21T00:00:00' AND '2019-01-24T00:00:00'  

SELECT[ConceptionName],[mainRoleCode],[UserName],sum(staff)[staff],[date] 
into #TestPivot 
FROM #Test group by [ConceptionName],[mainRoleCode],[UserName],[date] 
SELECT[date] into #TestPivotDate 
FROM #Test 
GROUP BY [date] 
DECLARE @Dates nvarchar(MAX); select @Dates = stuff((select ',' + '[' + left(convert(nvarchar,[date], 120), 10) + ']' 
FROM #TestPivotDate ORDER BY [date] FOR xml path('')),1,1,'') DECLARE @SqlCode nvarchar(MAX); 

SELECT @SqlCode = '
SELECT p.*, ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Dates, ',', '+'), '[', 'ISNULL(['), ']', '], 0)') + ' AS [Итого]
FROM (
select [ConceptionName],[mainRoleCode],[UserName],' + @Dates + ' FROM #TestPivot pivot(sum([staff]) for [date] in (' + @Dates + ')) AS pvt
) p
 ORDER BY p.[ConceptionName]' 

EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCode 
DROP TABLE #Test,#TestPivot,#TestPivotDate
```

Comment: а могли бы посмотреть  вопрос, там модернизация этого запроса [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/939345/%D0%A3%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-null-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5-sql)