# Убрать NULL из таблицы в сложном запросе SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT [ConceptionName], [mainRoleCode], [UserName], [UnitTabel] as staff, 
    CAST([DateTime] AS date) AS date
INTO #Test 
FROM[Authorization] WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '2019-01-21T00:00:00' AND '2019-01-24T00:00:00'  

SELECT [ConceptionName], [mainRoleCode], [UserName], sum(staff) AS [staff], [date] 
INTO #TestPivot 
FROM #Test
GROUP BY [ConceptionName], [mainRoleCode], [UserName], [date] 

SELECT [date]
INTO #TestPivotDate 
FROM #Test 
GROUP BY [date]

DECLARE @Dates nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT @Dates = stuff((select ',' + '[' + left(convert(nvarchar,[date], 120), 10) + ']' FROM #TestPivotDate ORDER BY [date] FOR xml path('')),1,1,'')

DECLARE @SqlCode nvarchar(MAX); 

SELECT @SqlCode = '
    SELECT p.*, ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Dates, ',', '+'), '[', 'ISNULL(['), ']', '], 0)') + ' AS [Итого]
    FROM (
    select [ConceptionName],[mainRoleCode],[UserName],' + @Dates + ' FROM #TestPivot pivot(sum([staff]) for [date] in (' + @Dates + ')) AS pvt
    ) p
     ORDER BY p.[ConceptionName]' 

EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCode 

DROP TABLE #Test,#TestPivot,#TestPivotDate
```

Он выдает результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтобы в результате заместо NULL был пробел или 0  ?

при `pivot(sum(coalesce([staff],0)) for [date] in (' + @Dates + ')) AS pvt) p` выдает "Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "coalesce"

при `pivot(sum(isnull([staff],0)) for [date] in (' + @Dates + ')) AS pvt) p` выдает "Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "(".

при `pivot(isnull(sum([staff]),0) for [date] in (' + @Dates + ')) AS pvt ) p`
выдает  " isnull не является известным агрегатная функция."

Comment: Вместо `SELECT p.*` распишите `SELECT [ConceptionName],[mainRoleCode],[UserName], ISNULL([2019-01-20], 0) AS [2019-01-20],....` то ли  REPLACE-ом, то ли через подготовленную аналогично `@Dates` переменную

Comment: @DenisRubashkin логика ясна. Как реализовать не пойму

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1 - дополнить разворачиваемую таблицу нулями перед разворотом.

```
INSERT INTO #TestPivot ([ConceptionName], [mainRoleCode], [UserName], [staff], [date]) 
SELECT A.[ConceptionName], A.[mainRoleCode], A.[UserName], 0 [staff], B.[date] 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [ConceptionName], [mainRoleCode], [UserName] FROM #Test) AS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [date] FROM #Test) AS B
  ON NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #TestPivot C WHERE C.[ConceptionName] = A.[ConceptionName], AND C.[mainRoleCode] = A.[mainRoleCode] AND C.[UserName] = A.[UserName] AND C.[date] = B.[date])
```

Вариант 2 - динамически собирая скрипт заменить `p.*` на `COALESCE(P.[date1],0) AS [date1], COALESCE(P.[date2],0) AS [date2] …`

Comment: вариант 1  - "В инструкции SELECT INTO недопустимы одинаковые исходная и целевая таблицы."  пишет.
вариант 2 - вот его бы как то развернуть. но как автоматизировать, не зная заранее какие будут столбцы в @Dates  я не пойму

Comment: Вариант 1 исправил.

Comment: Вы @Dates и так динамически собираете. Второй список собираете точно так же, только вместо `[` и `]` обрамляете в `COALESCE(P.[` и `],0)`

Comment: вариант 1 - "Недопустимое имя объекта "#TestPivot"."  пишет        вариант 2 - мозгов не хватает

Comment: Этот кусок нужно вставить после SELECT … INTO #TestPivot

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в этом участке 
          pivot(sum([staff]) for [date] in (' + @Dates + ')) AS pvt
Добавить 
         pivot(isnull(sum([staff]),0) for [date] in (' + @Dates + ')) AS pvt
    ) p

Comment: Возвращает " isnull не является известным агрегатная функция."

Comment: Поместите isnull внутрь агрегата, а лучше еще и замените на стандартную coalesce - pivot(sum(coalesce([staff],0))…

Comment: @ГерманБорисов  не получилось. добавил ответы ошибок в конец задачи